# Find two different elements $a$, $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^2 \equiv b^2 \equiv -1 (\mod 17)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

A solution to this problem is the following:

$$a = 4, \ b = 13$$ But I have no understanding of why these are correct answers, or how to go about thinking through the problem. If someone could kindly provide an explanation of the thought process I am supposed to use, and perhaps an example, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: When you square $x$, that's the same as squaring $-x$. But $-4$ is the same as $13\;(\text{mod}\;17)$. So assuming you understand why $4$ works, then it's automatic that $13$ also works, since $13$ is the same as $-4\;(\text{mod}\;17)$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Made an edit. It should have been 4, not -4. I do not understand why 4 or 13 work though.

Comment: @IgnorantCuriosity `I do not understand why 4 or 13 work though` $-1 =17-1=16$ in $\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}\,$, so $a^2+1=a^2-16=(a-4)(a+4)=(a-4)(a-13)\,$.

Comment: @IgnorantCuriosity: Just plug in $x=4$ into the congruence $x^2 = - 1\;(\text{mod}\;17)$, and see if the congruence is satisfied. And if $x=4$ works, then so does $x=-4$ since $(-4)^2 = 4^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Negative numbers are not special $\bmod p$, but it often helps to think about them by adding multiples of $p$ such that it becomes positive. For example, $-1 \equiv p - 1 \mod p$.

If you find one element that is $a^2 \equiv-1 \mod p$, then we can also say that $(-a)^2 \equiv (p - a)^2\equiv -1 \mod p$.

In this case we're kind of lucky, in that $p - 1$ already is a square.

So if we know $4^2 \equiv -1 \equiv 17 - 1 \equiv 16 \mod 17$, then $(-4)^2 \equiv (17 - 4)^2 \equiv 13^2 \equiv -1 \mod 17$.